# Lorentz Equation Symmetry

Tags: symmetry, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems

I was going via Lorentz equation & learning the topic on Symmetry, what I couldn't understand is how did they performed this type of substitution & what is the philosophy behind this way of substituting the equation as shown below in the pic, by philosophy of Symmetry what I wanted to convey is, Is it necessary for the system to have same co-ordinate symmetry in order to synchronize 2 chaotic circuits?. Can any one mention some of the applications of this concept on symmetry with reference to Chaos theory.

[image: Pic Showing the Substitution]

Comment: Why was this tagged with chaos-theory? Please don't post screenshots of text. It breaks search functionality, and it doesn't work for blind users.

Answer (score 1):

They just replaced $x$ with $-x$, and similarly for $y$. As in that case the equations did not change, the equations are symmetric with respect to this replacement.